# Filtering an array of objects into two new arrays and saving each to useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects

```
const units = [
   {id: 1, status: "AVAILABLE"}, 
   {id: 1, status: "ASSIGNED"},
   {...}
]
```

My goal is write a function that filters the array into two new arrays -- one array for objects that have `status: "AVAILABLE"` and another array for objects that have `status: "ASSIGNED"`

I'm setting state

```
const [availableUnits, setAvailableUnits] = useState([]);
const [assignedUnits, setAssignedUnits] = useState([]);
```

I want to filter through the units array and set each new array to its given state. I was trying do something like this:

```
setAvailableUnits(() => units.filter((unit) => {
     return unit.status === "AVAILABLE";
}))
```

This doesn't work though. I'd like one function that filters and sets state for both statuses.

Thank you.

Comment: I would avoid this. Set state with the data, and then use a function when you're mapping/filtering the data out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this as below code

```
setAvailableUnits(data.filter((v)=> v.status === "AVAILABLE"));
setAssignedUnits(data.filter((v)=> v.status === "ASSIGNED"));
```

Answer (score 1):

if `units` is already known before rendering the component you can try this

```
const [availableUnits, setAvailableUnits] = useState(units.filter((v)=> v.status === "AVAILABLE"));
const [assignedUnits, setAssignedUnits] = useState(units..filter((v)=> v.status === "ASSIGNED"));
```

if not and it comes from `fetching` for example

you can try

```
setAvailableUnits(data.filter((v)=> v.status === "AVAILABLE"));
setAssignedUnits(data.filter((v)=> v.status === "ASSIGNED"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if there are just two statuses available: `AVAILABLE` and `ASSIGNED`. Modify the if statement if you want to include more statuses.

```
const units = [
   {id: 1, status: "AVAILABLE"}, 
   {id: 1, status: "ASSIGNED"},
];

const newAvailableUnits = [];
const newAssignedUnits = [];

units.forEach((unit) => {
    if (unit.status === "AVAILABLE") newAvailableUnits.push(unit);
    else newAssignedUnits.push(unit);
})

setAvailableUnits(newAvailableUnits);
setAssignedUnits(newAssignedUnits);
```